# undefined local variable or method `int' for Request:Class(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error

I am facing a problem that when ever I open the form "service_create" it throws an error saying "undefined local variable or method". I do not know what I am doing wrong please tell me what is the problem(I am new to rails). Thanks

service_request

```
<%= link_to("Back" , {:action => '#'}) %>




<%= form_for(:request , :url => {:action => 'service_request_create'}) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :corresponding_user_from %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :corresponding_user_from %>

  </div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_service_location %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :product_service_location %>

  </div>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>

  <!--<%= f.select :category, @categories %>
-->

  <div class="field">
    <% f.collection_select(:category_id , Category.all , :_id , :title) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.radio_button :negotiable, "Yes" %>
    <%= f.label :negotiable, "Yes", :value => "Yes" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :negotiable, "No" %>
    <%= f.label :negotiable, "No", :value => "No" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Upper_price_range %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Upper_price_range %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lower_price_range %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :lower_price_range %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tags %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

request_controller.rb

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_request, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /requests
  # GET /requests.json
  def index

  end
  def active
    user      = session[:user] 
    @requests = Array.new
    @category = Array.new
    @requests = Request.getRequestByUser(user)
      @requests.each.with_index do |request, index|
      if request != nil
        @category[index] = Array.new
        request[:category_id].each do |cate|
          @category[index] << Category.getCategory(cate)
        end
      end
    end
  end
  # GET /requests/1
  # GET /requests/1.json
  def show
    @user     = User.getUser(@request[:user_id])
    @category = Array.new
    @request[:category_id].each do |cate|
      @category << Category.getCategory(cate)
    end
  end

  # GET /requests/1/edit
  def edit
    @category = Array.new
    @request[:category_id].each do |cate|
        @category << Category.getCategory(cate)
    end
  end
  # POST /requests
  def post_request
    tags         = params[:tags] ;
    categories   = Array.new ;
    if tags != nil
      tags.each do |tag|
        category  = Category.createCategoryIfNotExist(tag)
        if(category != nil)
          categories << category[:_id] 
        end
      end
    end
    request_data                = request_params
    user_id                     = session[:user] 
    request_data[:category_id]  = categories 
    request_data[:user_id]      = user_id
    @request_                   = Request.createRequest(request_data)
    if @request_
      flash[:notice] = "Request Post successfully."
      redirect_to :action => "active"
    end
  end

  #POST /requests
  def service_request
  end

  def item_request
  end

  def service_request_create
    request_data                = request_params_create
    user_id                     = session[:user] 
    request_data[:is_service]  = "on"
    request_data[:user_id]      = user_id
    #requests_data[:category]
    @request_                   = Request.createRequest(request_data)
    if @request_
      flash[:notice] = "Request Post successfully."
      redirect_to :action => "active"
    end
  end 

  def item_service_create
    #@req = Request.new(request_params)
  #@req.typee="Item"
   # if @req.save
   #   redirect_to(:action => 'rpage')
   # else
   #   render('new')
   # end
  end 




  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1
  # PATCH/PUT /requests/1.json
  def update
    tags         = params[:tags] ;
    categories   = Array.new ;
    if tags != nil
      tags.each do |tag|
        category  = Category.createCategoryIfNotExist(tag)
        if(category != nil)
          categories << category[:_id] 
        end
      end
    end
    Rails.logger.info("RequestsParams: #{request_params.inspect}")
    request_data                = request_params
    if request_data[:is_service] != "on"
       request_data[:is_service] = "off" 
    end
    user_id                     = session[:user] 
    request_data[:category_id]  = categories 
    request_data[:user_id]      = user_id
    if Request.updateRequest(@request,request_data)
      flash[:notice] = "Request has been Edited successfully."
      redirect_to :action => "active"
    end
  end
  def delete_request ()
    if Request.delete_request(params[:id])
      flash[:notice] = "Request has been Deleted successfully."
      render :json => "great"
    end
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_request
      @request = Request.getRequest(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def request_params
      params.require(:request).permit(:title, :description ,:type , :is_service )
    end

    def request_params_create
      params.require(:request).permit(:title, :description,  :corresponding_user_from, :category_id ,:product_service_location , :negotiable ,:Upper_price_range , :lower_price_range, :tags)
    end
end
```

Since I need a reputation of 10 to post an image I am posting a link of the screenshot of my error

Error Image

http://i57.tinypic.com/vxgfom.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the category_id in your Request model must be Integer, not int.